# How to prove the SOP and POS are equivalent to one another in XOR Funtion?

Tags: boolean-algebra

Write two Boolean expressions for the Exclusive-OR function, one written in SOP form and the other written in POS form. Simplify both expressions using Boolean algebra reduction and show that the two expressions are equivalent to one another. Draw the simplified circuit diagram for this function.

So, I've got

A B Output

1 1 0

1 0 1

0 1 1

0 0 0

SOP: A(B)'+(A)'B

POS: ((A)'+(B)')(A+B)

How to show that A(B)'+(A)'B = ((A)'+(B)')(A+B)

Comment: Just draw the truth tables for both

Comment: De Morgan's Rules !  ?    https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqaMW.png

Comment: just expand the POS and note that E'.E=0.

Comment: Could you tell me how to expand POS?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply?  Take the POS and multiply it out.  Distributive Law.  Show us what you have tried or are stuck on.  We will help, but an answer gains you nothing.